# Django React page can't load css files

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am creating an application with djangorest framework
for backend and React for frontend. The backend and frontend are both apps of the same django projects. However, while hosting my website, the CSS files are not loading, most probably because of the path.

The directory structure in my `frontend` django app looks like:

```
$ tree -d -L 1
.
├── migrations
├── node_modules
├── __pycache__
├── src
├── static
└── templates
```

and the templates directory looks like this:

```
templates/
└── frontend
    ├── css
    │   ├── bootstrap.css
    │   ├── bootstrap.css.map
    │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
    │   ├── bootstrap-theme.css
    │   ├── bootstrap-theme.css.map
    │   ├── bootstrap-theme.min.css
    │   ├── fontAwesome.css
    │   ├── fonts
    │   │   ├── flexslider-icon.eot
    │   │   ├── flexslider-icon.svg
    │   │   ├── flexslider-icon.ttf
    │   │   └── flexslider-icon.woff
    │   ├── light-box.css
    │   ├── owl-carousel.css
    │   └── templatemo-style.css
    └── index.html
```

My `index.html` file looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>abcd</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/frontend/css/fontAwesome.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <!-- React will load here -->
</div>
</body>
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}"></script>
</html>
```

and I run into the following log while hosting the site:

```
[30/Jun/2020 22:39:59] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1154
Not Found: /css/bootstrap.min.css
[30/Jun/2020 22:39:59] "GET /css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2313
Not Found: /css/fontAwesome.css
[30/Jun/2020 22:39:59] "GET /css/fontAwesome.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2307
[30/Jun/2020 22:39:59] "GET /static/frontend/main.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1004248
[30/Jun/2020 22:40:00] "GET /api/event HTTP/1.1" 301 0
```

I am not sure how to set the path for the css files and if they are even supposed to be in the directory I have put them in. WHat is the correct directory structure if my react app is a django app in my project?

Answer (score 0):

Your `css` folder shouldn't be in your `templates` folder, it shoud be in your `static` folder. Only this folder gets exposed to the outside world. The template folder is just a place where django gets its templates to render them to the client, but it does not expose it directly.

Also don't forget to run `python manage.py collectstatic` as well.

Comment: where are these folders configured? since I created them myself in my case

Comment: currently running the collectstatic command, copies my CSS files into a static folder in my project(one level above frontend) directory. However, the CSS files are still not loading